# Windows Explorer Recursive Copy Unknown File Types

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, powershell

I am attempting to move all files (several different types of files, potentially) from a single root directory and all nested folders within the root.  There could several different levels of sub-directories within each branch of the tree and I need to grab every file at each level without knowing ahead of time how many levels there might be.  In all honesty, I have not really tried anything yet.  In the past, I might have written something short and sweet in Python, but I would like to make this happen with a logon/logoff script in PowerShell and not make Python a prerequisite.  I know much less than I should about PS; if somebody could please point me in the general direction of a Powershell solution, or really anything that is minimally invasive, I am more than happy to do any amount of research necessary to pull it off.  I just need a nudge in the right direction.  Any help is greatly appreciated; I know this is a very unusual request.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a batch script (if you want to retain subdirectory structure)

Syntax is:

```
move "C:\path to\source folder\" "C:\path to\destination\"
pause
```

I've include a pause so that you can verify if it has been moved or not, remove it if you want the window to automatically close.

Example (I ran it in Command Prompt):

```
C:\Users\Dev>move "C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\New folder\lol" "C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Ne
w folder\lel"
        1 dir(s) moved.
```

If you are unfamiliar with batch files, just type in a notepad and save as anything.bat

This is much simpler than powershell, and you can put the script in the startup directory for whenever you log on.

Comment: Thank you, EMINEM, I really appreciate the feedback.  I am not much of a CLI person in general. I actually don't want to retain the original folder structure.  Ideally, this script would move all nested files into one large repository, no matter how deep the original file existed in the file structure.

Comment: If I attempt to to put this in pseudo code it looks something like this: mkdir C:\HoldingPen

Answer (score 0):

This requires PowerShell 3:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\SourceFolder -File | 
    % { Move-Item -WhatIf $_.FullName C:\DestFolder }
```

Note the `-WhatIf`. This will prevents the move command from actually executing. It will instead show in the console what it would do. Once you are satisfied it will do what you want, you can remove the `-WhatIf` and execute it for real.

Comment: You can also use `-Confirm` in this case.